# Dockerfile not COPY pakcage json

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My folder structure is like this

```
project/
   -backend/
       Dockerfile
       package.json
   - docker-compose.yml
```

My dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM node:14-alpine as base

WORKDIR /src
COPY ./package*.json /src
EXPOSE 3000


FROM base as dev
ENV NODE_ENV=development
RUN npm install -g nodemon && npm install
COPY . /
CMD ["npm run start:dev"]
```

just a simple dockerfile, nothing crazy

and my docker-compose like

```
version: '3'
services:

  web:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      target: dev
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    command: npm run start:dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      DEBUG: nodejs-docker-express:*
```

When I do docker-compose up an error shows up saying

```
web_1  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
web_1  | npm ERR! syscall open
web_1  | npm ERR! path /src/package.json
web_1  | npm ERR! errno -2
web_1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/package.json'
web_1  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
web_1  | npm ERR! enoent
web_1  |
web_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
web_1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-05-22T20_54_52_629Z-debug.log
```

This means that the package.json hasn't been copied I know.
But what I don't know is how to fix it.
I think the error is in the dockerfile but I coulnd't fix it

can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `volumes:` directive is replacing everything the Dockerfile built into the image with content from the host system, including the `package.json` file.  Does deleting that `volumes:` block improve things?  Do you get the error while building the image (does `docker-compose build` on its own work?) or while running it?

Comment: I got the error when running `docker compose up`

Comment: you gave me an idea.
in the volumes I add 
`
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/src
` and it's working 
thankm you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out by editing your docker compose, you have a problem in your volumes that is copying the hole project directory.

replace

```
    volumes:
      - .:/src
```

with

```
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/src
```